# Is _MM_SET_ROUNDING_MODE(STMXCSR) thread safe?

Tags: c++, multithreading, simd, sse2

I am using SIMD with SSE2 instruction set, I want to convert values from double to float using **_mm_cvtpd_ps**. But I need control over the rounding mode which is used. We are also using multithreading.

So I want to know is it thread safe to use **_MM_SET_ROUNDING_MODE(STMXCSR)** which changes the value in the MXCSR register to change the rounding mode.

If **NO** is there some other way to change the rounding mode of **_mm_cvtpd_ps** which is threadsafe.

Comment: Depends on the OS, but any half-baked one will include MXCSR in the thread state.  Yes.